# Emulate texture reading with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Graphics platforms, for example OpenGL, have functions to read from a texture by coordinates. One defines a texture image and can then read from arbitrary (even floating point) coordinates inside that image. Most platforms also offer to do interpolation.

**Is there a function/library in Python/Numpy that can emulate such behavior?**

Would be very useful, not exactly in the context of computer graphics, but for interpolated reading in a 2-dimensional lookup-table that is stored like an image.

Comment: Look into `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't find it before, even though I browsed through the package...